# In Jetpack Compose with Navigation Compose, do I no longer need to create a new activity for each screen?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm not a good Android Dev specialist, I'm still learning. When I started learning Jetpack Compose, I had this question. Previously, on the View system, when I needed to create a new screen, I created a new activity. But now that Navigation Compose exists, I don't see the point in doing so. Do I understand correctly that with the advent of Navigation Compose, one activity will be enough for most apps (except for some specific cases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in Jetpack compose it is very easy to use one Activity and multiple screen and it uses very often as you mentioned in most app single activity will be enough to do all of your work and as you get used to Jetpack compose you prefer to use single activity and multiple screen.